# Call custom made function from svg element using AngularJs and D3.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, svg, d3.js, scope

I'm currently using AngularJS I'm trying to implement a graph in D3.js that needs to have some functionalities.

So my first step was to try to launch some custom function when I double clicked on one element of the graph.

At first I tried adding an AngularJS directive like "ng-click" or "ng-dblclick" but it simply didn't work.

Now I'm adding ".on("dblclick", function (d) { alert('You have clicked the circle.'); })"
to the circle element and it is working but only if the function is something like "alert" and not something custom made like

```
self.GoBackToPage = function (PageId) {
    viewModelHelper.navigateToPage(PageId);
};
```

I'm no Javascript expert by any means so I'm not sure what is the problem here, maybe self.GoBackToPage is not defined in the scope in which "self.update" operates, but I've also tried to define my custom function inside of "self.update" and it didn't work out.

It doesn't give me any error in the console when I try to call GoBackToPage instead of alert, it appears like the function doesn't even exist.

```js
function MyController($scope) {

  var self = this;
  self.model = {
    id: -1,
    links: {},
  };

  self.$onInit = function() {
    self.GetLinks(self.model.id);
    self.firstRender();
  };

  self.GoBackToPage = function(PageId) {
    viewModelHelper.navigateToPage(PageId);
  };

  var links = [];
  var nodes = {};
  var w = 1400,
    h = 900;
  var force;
  var svg;
  var paths;
  var circles;
  var texts;
  var pathLabels;

  self.GetLinks = function(id) {
    viewModelHelper.apiGet("Api/GetLinks/" + id,
      null,
      function(result) {
        links = result;
        self.update();
      }
    )
  };

  self.firstRender = function() {
    force = d3.layout.force()
      .size([w, h])
      .linkDistance(200)
      .charge(-1200)
      .on("tick", tick);

    svg = d3.select("body").append("svg:svg")
      .attr("width", w)
      .attr("height", h);

    // Per-type markers, as they don't inherit styles.
    svg.append("svg:defs").selectAll("marker")
      .data(["suit", "licensing", "resolved"])
      .enter().append("svg:marker")
      .attr("id", String)
      .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
      .attr("refX", 15)
      .attr("refY", -1.5)
      .attr("markerWidth", 6)
      .attr("markerHeight", 6)
      .attr("orient", "auto")
      .append("svg:path")
      .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");

    paths = svg.append("svg:g");
    circles = svg.append("svg:g");
    texts = svg.append("svg:g");
    pathLabels = svg.append("svg:g");
  }

  self.update = function() {
    // Compute the distinct nodes from the links.
    links.forEach(function(link) {
      link.source = nodes[link.source] || (nodes[link.source] = {
        name: link.source
      });
      link.target = nodes[link.target] || (nodes[link.target] = {
        name: link.target
      });
    });

    force
      .nodes(d3.values(nodes))
      .links(links)
      .start();

    var path = paths.selectAll("path")
      .data(force.links());

    path.exit()
      .remove();
    path.enter()
      .append("svg:path");

    path.attr("id", function(d) {
        return d.source.index + "_" + d.target.index;
      })
      .attr("class", function(d) {
        return "link " + d.type;
      })
      .attr("marker-end", function(d) {
        return "url(#" + d.type + ")";
      });

    var circle = circles.selectAll(".circle")
      .data(force.nodes());

    circle.exit()
      .remove();
    circle.enter()
      .append("svg:circle")
      .attr("class", "circle")
      .attr("r", 16)
      .on("dblclick", function(d) {
        console.log('You have clicked the circle.');
      })
      .call(force.drag);

    var text = texts.selectAll("g")
      .data(force.nodes());

    text.exit()
      .remove();
    text.enter()
      .append("svg:text")
      .attr("x", 2)
      .attr("y", 50) //".31em"

    text.text(function(d) {
      return d.name;
    });

    var pathLabel = pathLabels
      .selectAll(".path_label")
      .data(force.links());

    pathLabel.exit().remove();
    pathLabel.enter()
      .append("svg:text")
      .attr("class", "path_label")
      .append("svg:textPath")
      .attr("startOffset", "50%")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .style("fill", "#000")
      .style("font-family", "Arial");

    pathLabel
      .attr("xlink:href", function(d) {
        return "#" + d.source.index + "_" + d.target.index;
      })
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.type;
      });
  }

  // Use elliptical arc path segments to doubly-encode directionality.
  function tick() {
    paths.selectAll("path").attr("d", function(d) {
      var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
        dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
        dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
      return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
    });

    circles.selectAll("circle").attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    });

    texts.selectAll("text").attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    });
  }
}

angular.module("app", [])
  .controller("ctrl", MyController);

var viewModelHelper = {
  apiGet: function(a, b, then) {
    setTimeout(
      function() {
        console.log("Response from server");
        then(viewModelHelper.links);
      },
      2000
    );
  },
  navigateToPage: function(pageId) {
    console.log("Navigate to page", pageId);
  },
  links: [{
      source: "Microsoft",
      target: "Amazon",
      type: "licensing"
    },
    {
      source: "Microsoft",
      target: "HTC",
      type: "licensing"
    },
    {
      source: "Samsung",
      target: "Apple",
      type: "suit"
    },
    {
      source: "Motorola",
      target: "Apple",
      type: "suit"
    },
    {
      source: "Nokia",
      target: "Apple",
      type: "resolved"
    },
    {
      source: "HTC",
      target: "Apple",
      type: "suit"
    },
    {
      source: "Kodak",
      target: "Apple",
      type: "suit"
    },
    {
      source: "Microsoft",
      target: "Barnes & Noble",
      type: "suit"
    },
    {
      source: "Microsoft",
      target: "Foxconn",
      type: "suit"
    },
    {
      source: "Oracle",
      target: "Google",
      type: "suit"
    },
    {
      source: "Apple",
      target: "HTC",
      type: "suit"
    },
    {
      source: "Microsoft",
      target: "Inventec",
      type: "suit"
    },
    {
      source: "Samsung",
      target: "Kodak",
      type: "resolved"
    },
    {
      source: "LG",
      target: "Kodak",
      type: "resolved"
    },
    {
      source: "RIM",
      target: "Kodak",
      type: "suit"
    },
    {
      source: "Sony",
      target: "LG",
      type: "suit"
    },
    {
      source: "Kodak",
      target: "LG",
      type: "resolved"
    },
    {
      source: "Apple",
      target: "Nokia",
      type: "resolved"
    },
    {
      source: "Qualcomm",
      target: "Nokia",
      type: "resolved"
    },
    {
      source: "Apple",
      target: "Motorola",
      type: "suit"
    },
    {
      source: "Microsoft",
      target: "Motorola",
      type: "suit"
    },
    {
      source: "Motorola",
      target: "Microsoft",
      type: "suit"
    },
    {
      source: "Huawei",
      target: "ZTE",
      type: "suit"
    },
    {
      source: "Ericsson",
      target: "ZTE",
      type: "suit"
    },
    {
      source: "Kodak",
      target: "Samsung",
      type: "resolved"
    },
    {
      source: "Apple",
      target: "Samsung",
      type: "suit"
    },
    {
      source: "Kodak",
      target: "RIM",
      type: "suit"
    },
    {
      source: "Nokia",
      target: "Qualcomm",
      type: "suit"
    },
    {
      source: "Pippo",
      target: "Pippo"
    },
    {
      source: "Paperino",
      target: "Pippo",
      type: "suit"
    }
  ],
};
```

```css
path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
</div>
```

Here at the end `var viewModelHelper` is there to mock the result of the ApiGet Call `GetLinks`.

There is pretty much no HTML in MyHTML.cshtml, only this line that is used by d3 in "self.firstrender" to append the svg element to the page, all the elements of the HTML are created here in the JS:

```
    <bodyMYHTML></bodyMYHTML>
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason that `ng-click` and `ng-dblclick` don't work is because the AngularJS `$compile`r is unaware that this element has been added to the DOM, so it can't perform the necessary preparations to make `ng-*` work.

But since you insert the code inside an AngularJS controller, you shouldn't need to use these types of `ng-*` directives. Instead, you can just access `self` and `viewModelHelper` directly inside the functions. That is why the following just works.

I think there either might not be a `navigateToPage` function on the `viewModelHelper`, or you might have misspelled something. I couldn't find `PageId` anywhere on your example, so I used `d.name` instead.

```js
function MyController($scope) {

  var self = this;
  self.model = {
    id: -1,
    links: {},
  };

  self.$onInit = function() {
    self.GetLinks(self.model.id);
    self.firstRender();
  };

  self.GoBackToPage = function(PageId) {
    viewModelHelper.navigateToPage(PageId);
  };

  var links = [];
  var nodes = {};
  var w = 1400,
    h = 900;
  var force;
  var svg;
  var paths;
  var circles;
  var texts;
  var pathLabels;

  self.GetLinks = function(id) {
    viewModelHelper.apiGet("Api/GetLinks/" + id,
      null,
      function(result) {
        links = result;
        self.update();
      }
    )
  };

  self.firstRender = function() {
    force = d3.layout.force()
      .size([w, h])
      .linkDistance(200)
      .charge(-1200)
      .on("tick", tick);

    svg = d3.select("body").append("svg:svg")
      .attr("width", w)
      .attr("height", h);

    // Per-type markers, as they don't inherit styles.
    svg.append("svg:defs").selectAll("marker")
      .data(["suit", "licensing", "resolved"])
      .enter().append("svg:marker")
      .attr("id", String)
      .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
      .attr("refX", 15)
      .attr("refY", -1.5)
      .attr("markerWidth", 6)
      .attr("markerHeight", 6)
      .attr("orient", "auto")
      .append("svg:path")
      .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");

    paths = svg.append("svg:g");
    circles = svg.append("svg:g");
    texts = svg.append("svg:g");
    pathLabels = svg.append("svg:g");
  }

  self.update = function() {
    // Compute the distinct nodes from the links.
    links.forEach(function(link) {
      link.source = nodes[link.source] || (nodes[link.source] = {
        name: link.source
      });
      link.target = nodes[link.target] || (nodes[link.target] = {
        name: link.target
      });
    });

    force
      .nodes(d3.values(nodes))
      .links(links)
      .start();

    var path = paths.selectAll("path")
      .data(force.links());

    path.exit()
      .remove();
    path.enter()
      .append("svg:path");

    path.attr("id", function(d) {
        return d.source.index + "_" + d.target.index;
      })
      .attr("class", function(d) {
        return "link " + d.type;
      })
      .attr("marker-end", function(d) {
        return "url(#" + d.type + ")";
      });

    var circle = circles.selectAll(".circle")
      .data(force.nodes());

    circle.exit()
      .remove();
    circle.enter()
      .append("svg:circle")
      .attr("class", "circle")
      .attr("r", 16)
      .on("dblclick", function(d) {
        self.GoBackToPage(d.name)
      })
      .call(force.drag);

    var text = texts.selectAll("g")
      .data(force.nodes());

    text.exit()
      .remove();
    text.enter()
      .append("svg:text")
      .attr("x", 2)
      .attr("y", 50) //".31em"

    text.text(function(d) {
      return d.name;
    });

    var pathLabel = pathLabels
      .selectAll(".path_label")
      .data(force.links());

    pathLabel.exit().remove();
    pathLabel.enter()
      .append("svg:text")
      .attr("class", "path_label")
      .append("svg:textPath")
      .attr("startOffset", "50%")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .style("fill", "#000")
      .style("font-family", "Arial");

    pathLabel
      .attr("xlink:href", function(d) {
        return "#" + d.source.index + "_" + d.target.index;
      })
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.type;
      });
  }

  // Use elliptical arc path segments to doubly-encode directionality.
  function tick() {
    paths.selectAll("path").attr("d", function(d) {
      var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
        dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
        dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
      return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
    });

    circles.selectAll("circle").attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    });

    texts.selectAll("text").attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    });
  }
}

angular.module("app", [])
  .controller("ctrl", MyController);

var viewModelHelper = {
  apiGet: function(a, b, then) {
    setTimeout(
      function() {
        console.log("Response from server");
        then(viewModelHelper.links);
      },
      2000
    );
  },
  navigateToPage: function(pageId) {
    console.log("Navigate to page", pageId);
  },
  links: [{
      source: "Microsoft",
      target: "Amazon",
      type: "licensing"
    },
    {
      source: "Microsoft",
      target: "HTC",
      type: "licensing"
    },
    {
      source: "Samsung",
      target: "Apple",
      type: "suit"
    },
    {
      source: "Motorola",
      target: "Apple",
      type: "suit"
    },
    {
      source: "Nokia",
      target: "Apple",
      type: "resolved"
    },
    {
      source: "HTC",
      target: "Apple",
      type: "suit"
    },
    {
      source: "Kodak",
      target: "Apple",
      type: "suit"
    },
    {
      source: "Microsoft",
      target: "Barnes & Noble",
      type: "suit"
    },
    {
      source: "Microsoft",
      target: "Foxconn",
      type: "suit"
    },
    {
      source: "Oracle",
      target: "Google",
      type: "suit"
    },
    {
      source: "Apple",
      target: "HTC",
      type: "suit"
    },
    {
      source: "Microsoft",
      target: "Inventec",
      type: "suit"
    },
    {
      source: "Samsung",
      target: "Kodak",
      type: "resolved"
    },
    {
      source: "LG",
      target: "Kodak",
      type: "resolved"
    },
    {
      source: "RIM",
      target: "Kodak",
      type: "suit"
    },
    {
      source: "Sony",
      target: "LG",
      type: "suit"
    },
    {
      source: "Kodak",
      target: "LG",
      type: "resolved"
    },
    {
      source: "Apple",
      target: "Nokia",
      type: "resolved"
    },
    {
      source: "Qualcomm",
      target: "Nokia",
      type: "resolved"
    },
    {
      source: "Apple",
      target: "Motorola",
      type: "suit"
    },
    {
      source: "Microsoft",
      target: "Motorola",
      type: "suit"
    },
    {
      source: "Motorola",
      target: "Microsoft",
      type: "suit"
    },
    {
      source: "Huawei",
      target: "ZTE",
      type: "suit"
    },
    {
      source: "Ericsson",
      target: "ZTE",
      type: "suit"
    },
    {
      source: "Kodak",
      target: "Samsung",
      type: "resolved"
    },
    {
      source: "Apple",
      target: "Samsung",
      type: "suit"
    },
    {
      source: "Kodak",
      target: "RIM",
      type: "suit"
    },
    {
      source: "Nokia",
      target: "Qualcomm",
      type: "suit"
    },
    {
      source: "Pippo",
      target: "Pippo"
    },
    {
      source: "Paperino",
      target: "Pippo",
      type: "suit"
    }
  ],
};
```

```css
path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
</div>
```